# CakePHP Containable: Same model in deep association

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3, containable

I searched quite some for this, but I don't even know what to call it.

In a simplified version, I have these Models:

- `Person` (id, name) - hasMany: `ArrivalDate`
- `Country` (id, name) - hasMany: `Person`
- `ArrivalDate` (id, arrival_date, salesman_id) - belongsTo: `Person`, `Salesman` (className => `Person`)

As you can see, I'm trying to have the people with arrival dates and the salesmen in ONE TABLE.

Upon retrieving the data I use the containable behavior to get only the models I want.

```
$person = $this->Person->find('first', array(
    'conditions' => array('Person.id' => $id),
    'contain' => array(
        'Country',
        'ArrivalDate'
    )
));
```

But the question is: **How do I "contain" the `Salesman` in this?**

`Salesman` is just an alias for the `Person` and if I contain the `Person` model I just get the parent data. If I try to contain the alias (`Salesman`) I get an error.

Comment: It's called a self-referencing association.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
'contain' => array(
        'Country',
        'ArrivalDate',
        'ArrivalDate.Salesman' => array( insert needed fields here ... )
    )
```

should work in your case

Comment: Thank you, very simple. I discovered that the problem I had was complicated by a virtual field in the Person model.